# How to access custom fields of a page in the theme template

Tags: liferay, velocity

I'd like to use custom fields to display some page specific strings in the theme.

I have created a custom field "intro" of type Textbox.

How do I access the data in the theme template (velocity)?

As there is no "introspection" which variables are declared, I find it very difficult to figure out how to access them. The documentation is far from usable on the topic of custom fields :-/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you definde custom attribute in a page than you can use

```
$layout.getExpandoBridge().getAttribute("intro")
```

Also see javadoc or source for `com.liferay.portlet.expando.model.ExpandoBridge`

Comment: Thanks! The liferay documentation really needs a makeover :-/ I searched for at least 2h and found nothing...

Comment: I agree. Best friends, for some Liferay's features, are Liferay's source and search through files :)

Comment: I did no in depth search, but I think that I'll need to do that more often from now on with liferay...

Answer (score 1):

if you need  use in template FTL, in my case  for menu  navigation template

<#assign prop = navItem.getLayout().getExpandoBridge().getAttribute("prop_name") >

Answer (score 1):

Work for me in Liferay 7+:

Create a custom field type "site", fill data into site settings, and use into theme template for call this data into liferay theme:

If a VM file:

```
#set ($site_custom_field = $layout.getGroup().getExpandoBridge().getAttribute("site_custom_field_key"))
<h1>$site_custom_field</h1>
```

If a FTL file:

```
<#assign site_custom_field = layout.getGroup().getExpandoBridge().getAttribute("site_custom_field_key")>
<h1>${site_custom_field}</h1>
```

Have a nice day!